# 0Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined , Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: jquery, angularjs

hey iam trying to move to another page by clicking the button using angular js
My js is home.js, but i couldn't make it.
also i can't alert any data in that js

```
    var base_url="http://localhost/cityMob/mob/"; 
 var app = angular.module('home', []);       
  app.controller('homeCtrl', function ($scope, $http,$window) {

$scope.cityname = null;
$scope.cityName = [];
$scope.sign_up = function() {
    $window.location.href = 'signup.html';
};


 });


      <body  class="bodybgColor ui-mobile-viewport ui-overlay-a" ng-app="home" ng-controller="homeCtrl">
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your html code as and seems working

```
<body  class="bodybgColor ui-mobile-viewport ui-overlay-a" ng-app="home" ng-    controller="homeCtrl"> 
{{ 9+9 }}
<button ng-click="sign_up()"> sign up</button>
</body>
```

here is link http://dojo.telerik.com/ERazU
hope this will help you